# VBA script to save as in Presentation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a Visual Basic script that, when called, will open a SaveAs dialog in PowerPoint file, with the svg format option pre-selected. The script must be executable by a function and work on recent versions of Microsoft Office.

I tried the following approach, but I get an error in the method:`Application.GetSaveAsFilename`

```vb
Sub SaveAsSVG()
    Dim SavePath As Variant
    Dim FileFormat As Integer
    
    FileFormat = 18 
    
    SavePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Scalable Vector Graphics (*.svg), *.svg", , "Save As SVG")
    
    If SavePath <> "False" Then
        ActivePresentation.SaveAs SavePath, FileFormat
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: GetSaveAsFileName is an Excel method, not PowerPoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename

Answer (score 1):

Just like `John Korchok` said,

> GetSaveAsFileName is an Excel method, not PowerPoint.

If you have to use this method, then you should initiate a Excel app instance before to invoke this mothed, so your code should be like this instead, and you'll no longer to see

> an error in the method:`Application.GetSaveAsFilename`

```vb
Sub SaveAsSVG()
    Dim SavePath As Variant
    Dim FileFormat As Integer
    
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
    
    FileFormat = 18
    
    'SavePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Scalable Vector Graphics (*.svg), *.svg", , "Save As SVG")
    SavePath = excelApp.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Scalable Vector Graphics (*.svg), *.svg", , "Save As SVG")
    
    If SavePath <> "False" Then
        ActivePresentation.SaveAs SavePath, FileFormat
    End If
End Sub
```